Navigate to a specific static tab from configurable tab in microsoft teams
Wanted to navigate from configurable tabs to static tabs without redirecting the user to a new tab
I want to navigate to teams static tab from configurable tab loaded in "meetingSidePanel" context. but i am not able to navigate/ deeplink.
am using this microsoft client library
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/@microsoft/teams-js@1.5.0/dist/MicrosoftTeams.min.js" 
  integrity="sha384-EKT9Wswdn78EAHAqcOh50wnaPfH3aPa7YZ1R89/TCN98AhkqZJ2g47u4k2I5eCk8" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</script>

I tried following ways.
url = https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/<appId>/<entityIdOfStaticTab> 
window.open(url) => opening the link in new tab instead of navigating inside teams


var tabInstance = {
        tabName: "Home",
        entityId: "home",
        internalTabInstanceId:"home"
    };
     
function handleSuccess() {
    console.log("Navigation to the tab was successful!");
}
     
function handleError(error) {
    console.error("Error during navigation:", error);
}
microsoftTeams.navigateToTab(tabInstance, handleSuccess, handleError);

=> This always gives a success response but nothing happens

microsoftTeams.executeDeepLink(url) => 

Error: This call is not allowed in the 'sidePanel' context

Not sure if we have any other way. Any help will be appreciated.

Could you please try with the navigateTo TeamsJS library function
function navigateTo(params: NavigateWithinAppParams): Promise<void>

Ref Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@microsoft/teams-js/pages.currentapp?view=msteams-client-js-latest#@microsoft-teams-js-pages-currentapp-navigateto
